# How to Scan a QR Code from Image Gallery in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, qr-code

I'm trying to scan a QR code from a saved image on a mobile device (not from a live camera).

I have successfully implemented ZXing to scan QR codes from a live camera.
But after scanning from the image, null is coming in the result object, what should I do to scan qrcode from the image?

My code is here:

```
var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
    var reader = new QRCodeReader();
    var binaryBitmap = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IImageHelper().GetBinaryBitmap(file.GetStream());
var result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);

public BinaryBitmap GetBinaryBitmap(Stream image)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(image);//DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);

            byte[] rgbBytes = GetRgbBytes(bitmap);
            var bin = new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            var i = new BinaryBitmap(bin);

            return i;
        }
private byte[] GetRgbBytes(Bitmap image)
        {
            var rgbBytes = new List<byte>();
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    var c = new Color(image.GetPixel(x, y));

                    rgbBytes.AddRange(new[] { c.R, c.G, c.B });
                }
            }
            return rgbBytes.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=zxing.net+QRCodeReader+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Could you please post the full log about your problem?